# How to read data from solr/data/index

Tags: java, file-io, indexing, solr

How to read data from `solr/data/index` by some simple console Java application? I found some [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049187/trying-to-get-java-to-read-lucene-index-created-with-solr).

But maybe there is more simple way. 
Help please with that, I really don't know what to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's my own solution. I get `index` files from solr 4.4 and I also use lucene-core-4.4.0.jar library. Maybe it can help someone.

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;

    import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
    import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader;
    import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.ParseException;
    import org.apache.lucene.store.Directory;
    import org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory;
    import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException;

    public class SomeClass {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


            Directory dirIndex = FSDirectory.open(new File("solr/home/data/index"));
            IndexReader indexReader = IndexReader.open(dirIndex);
            Document doc = null;   

            for(int i = 0; i < indexReader.numDocs(); i++) {
                doc = indexReader.document(i);
            }

            System.out.println(doc.toString());

            indexReader.close();
            dirIndex.close();
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a project called [Luke](https://github.com/DmitryKey/luke) which is a GUI for users to inspect Lucene indices.

[Here](https://datafireball.com/2016/03/08/luke-lucene-index-inspector/) is a blog post with more detail.[image]